# JVM Memory Types

Tags: java, memory, architecture, jvm, monitoring

I'm working on a monitoring project; we have the monitoring software working and recollecting the metrics from the server. Everything is working fine, but we need some information about the JVM Memory Usage details. We have some columns with different memory types. We need to know what these are:

- Heap
- Non Heap
- Usage
- Peak
- Coll

We've got maximums for all these columns (HeapMax, NonHeapMax, UsageMax, PeakMax and CollMax) and also used (HeapUsed, NonHeapUsed, UsageUsed, PeakUsed and CollUsed)

We know what Heap and NonHeap is, but we don't know about Usage, Peak and Coll.

Does anybody know what they are?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Usage :-** might be the memory currently being used (i.e. *Used:* in the image)

**Peak :-** might be the committed memory till the time (i.e. *Commited:* in the image)

**Coll :-** might be the maximum memory that can be used (i.e. *Max:* in the image)

*Max:* is fixed for the running JMV's lifetime.

*Used and Committed* : varies as per the load.

I have attached a snapshot of JConsole which lists these attributes.

Comment: JConsole snapshot is not visible in the post. I don't know why. but you can check therse attributes from JConsole or JVisualVM.